# Firestore - multiple add and update operations in one transaction

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, transactions

I have a Firestore document representing a day with a subcollection containing reservations for this day in a Firestore database.

Here is JSON example of my data structure:

```
{  
   "Day":{  
      "ReservationsCount":2,
      "Reservations":[  
         {  
            "Order":1
         },
         {  
            "Order":2
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I need to add a set of documents, set their ordinal number in collection and update the ReservationsCount in one transaction.

I tried to use firestore transactions and batched writes, but as far I understand, they do not support adding document to a collection in transaction (according to [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) only combination of set(), update(), or delete() operations).

I tried to do update the values using cloud functions, but they are in beta and there are [known issues with performance and reliability](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions#limitations_and_guarantees), so I got sometimes wrong results.

Is there any way to update existing document and add documents to its subcollection within one transaction?

Comment: Both `set()` and `update()` operations can create documents. If you're having a problem making this work, share the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3):

The following should do the trick. You have to pass to the `updateRes()` function the ref of the 'day" doc, the ref of the sub-collection and an array containing an object for each document to add to the sub-collection.

Just open the HTML file in a browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.4/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <script>

        var config = {
            apiKey: "...",
            authDomain: "...",
            databaseURL: "...",
            ....
        };

        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        var firestoredb = firebase.firestore();


        function updateRes(dayDocRef, orderCollectionRef, refAndDataArray) {

            return firestoredb.runTransaction(function (transaction) {

                return transaction.get(dayDocRef)
                    .then(function (dayDoc) {

                        if (!dayDoc.exists) {
                            throw "Document Day does not exist!";
                        }

                        newResCount = dayDoc.data().ReservationsCount + refAndDataArray.length;

                        return transaction.update(dayDocRef, { ReservationsCount: newResCount });

                    })
                    .then(function () {

                        var t = transaction;

                        refAndDataArray.forEach(function (element) {
                            t = t.set(orderCollectionRef.doc(element.ref), element.data);
                        });

                        return t;

                    });

            }).then(function () {
                console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log("Transaction failed: ", error);
            });

        };


        var dayDocRef = firestoredb.collection("Days").doc("Day");
        var orderCollectionRef = dayDocRef.collection("Reservations"); //The sub-collection is called "Reservations"

        var refAndDataArray = [{ ref: "3", data: { Order: 3, otherData: "foo" } }, { ref: "4", data: { Order: 4, otherData: "bar" } }];

        updateRes(dayDocRef, orderCollectionRef, refAndDataArray);


    </script>


</body>

</html>
```